# max-height causing javascript to stop functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks for all the attempts so far. But I feel that I've not been as clear so I've decided to rewrite this question. As I've been searching and searching for an answer, or fix, or SOMETHING to solve my problem.

Overview: My client wants a collage of images. When clicked, the images will open in prettyPhoto (a lightbox clone).

I'm using masonry.js to grid the images. I'm using imagesloaded.js to "lazy load" the thumbnails. Then I'm also using classie.js, AnimOnScroll.js, and modernizr.js.

So, when building the ul of thumbnails, everything works great. But when I plug it in to the existing site, it stops working.

The client's site has a layout similar to a framed site. Where the overall page is a certain height and there's a section in the middle (#mainbody) that scrolls when needed, like so:

```
---------------------------------------------
|                  HEADER                   |
---------------------------------------------
|     |                               |     |
|     |           MAINBODY            |     |
|     |          (scrolls)            |     |
|     |                               |     |
|     |                               |     |
---------------------------------------------
|                  FOOTER                   |
---------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that #mainbody scrolls, and the overall page scrolls, this causes only a few thumbnails to show up. The rest are there, but you can't see them.

I've set up a dummy site [here](http://www.squalle.com/test/) to demonstrate, instead of posting a ton of code on here. Hopefully that will make it easier.

Along with the two stylesheets (component.css for masonry.js and default.css) I've added test.css, which contains only the code for #mainbody. If you take the reference to test.css out, everything works fine.

Hopefully I've made everything a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I tried to add this as a comment but don't have enough rep yet.
So, the script is getting confused by that max-height and doesn't take it into account as it loads the images. You would probably have to adapt the script to refresh said max height as you're scrolling.
Alternatively (and this is a long shot), if the 160+ images are just in a long list have you tried adding some css to the initial unprocessed UL tag? like maybe float them all left. I'm saying this assuming that the script will re-write the UL styles in order to display the images in the intended way.

Comment: What's weird is that it loads the first, say 14 images or so (thumbnails). As you scroll, it's like the images are there, you just can't see them. You can click on where they would be and it'll open the lightbox. So the links all work ok, you just can't see the images. But like I said, the first 14 images work perfectly. I'm not very good with jquery yet so changing the script wouldn't be good for me. lol

Comment: Perhaps another option would be to make the Li tags position:absolute  in css. Hopefully that would remove the excess height and the script would do the rest as it gracefully loads the images

Comment: Unfortunately, same result. Only a few thumbnails showing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to nest the UL in another div, so max-height is on a parent div, like:

```
<div id="mainbody">
  <div id="galleryWrapper">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm a little confused with your CSS

```
#mainbody {    
  height: auto !important;
  height: 650px;
}
```

So *height auto* will always be used.

Comment: My understanding is that it's a hack for older IE, so it's not really needed, but if I take it out, the scrolling is ok, but the script only shows the first 14 images or so.

Comment: Ok, I tried nesting the ul like you suggested. Same result. The scolling is correct, but only the first few images load. Maybe I'll just try to find a different lazy loader script. The AnimOnScroll script loads images according to the scrollbar, so that's where it's going wrong. I just don't know how to fix it.